# Error exception - include(assets/grocery_crud/languages/english.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: codeigniter-4, grocery-crud

File and directory are there as per the grocery crud instructions. But its returning the above error exception in the following line

```
include ($this->default_language_path.'/'.($this->language).'.php');
```

path is already declared

```
protected $default_language_path    = 'assets/grocery_crud/languages';
```

CodeIgniter 4 and grocery crud supporting codeigniter4

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Where is your assets folder located relative to all of your other folders?

Comment: asset folder inside the public folder (/public/assets/grocery_crud/languages)

Answer (score 0):

solved..

the asset folder which comes along with the grocery-crud download should be placed in the root, not inside public folder

Comment: Well Not if you had made the "public" folder the document root. I rename public to public_html and set that as my document root.